# Saving settings on Phonegap/Javascript app

Tags: caching, cordova, cookies, html5-appcache

I have an Android Phonegap app made with HTML5/Javascript/CSS. I'd like to suggest the users to choose between light and dark themes at the very first start of the app. When the user once chooses one of them this chose should be saved and relevant theme should be set as default at evry further start of the app. I have read some posts on this theme and am not sure which solution to take: Cache, cookies or HTML5 local storage (I am not familiar with any of them). Which one fits better to my app?

Thank you all!

Comment: I'm a fan of localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` wins, simply for persistence and ease-of-use:

```
// set the selected theme
localStorage.setItem("appTheme") = "dark";
...
var lsTheme = localStorage.getItem("appTheme"),
    theme = (typeof lsTheme !== "undefined" ? lsTheme : "bright");
// do something with the selected theme; "bright" is default if no preference stored.
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is the simplest and most effective solution like Kerri Shotts said however the `setItem` methods syntax is different to that displayed in her answer. As it takes to parameters one being the `keyName` the other being the `keyValue` like so: `storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);` This then retrieved using the `getItem` method like so: `var aValue = storage.getItem(keyName);`.
e.g.

```
  localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'red');
  localStorage.setItem('font', 'Helvetica');
  localStorage.setItem('image', 'myCat.png');

  var currentColor = localStorage.getItem('bgcolor');
  var currentFont = localStorage.getItem('font');
  var currentImage = localStorage.getItem('image');
```